# Javascript/Jquery execution order issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, cdn

I am using external JavaScript to show video player on web page like...

```
<script src='http://player.field59.com/v3/vp/...........'></script>
```

Here is my code that cut the HTML code which is generated by above script tag and paste into specific container like `<div id='dynamic-video-container'></div>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){           

    if( $("div.subscriber-hide div.html-content div.bimVideoPlayer").length ) {       
        var video_content = $('<span>').append($('div.subscriber-hide div.bimVideoPlayer').clone()[0]).remove().html();            
    }

    $('div.subscriber-hide div.html-content').remove();            
    $("div#dynamic-video-container").html(video_content); 
});
```

I am doing this because I am not able to put external code directly into `"<div id='dynamic-video-container'></div>"` container.

My issue is this sometimes play functionality of video player is not working may be due to loading sequence of external code and code snippet.

Is there any option by which code snippet will execute when external js becomes fully loaded? Can anyone suggest idea to how to do this?

One more thing external code `"<script src='http://player.field59.com/v3/vp/...........'></script>"` is added by CMS so I am unable to change this line.

Comment: You could try [`$( window ).load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) which should fire only when all resources are loaded. Alternately, the brute force way is to identify a resource which, when available, indicates that your code will be functional when executed. Then use a [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) loop to poll until that resource is available.

Comment: What is displayed in the console when the failure occurs?

Comment: @Makyen when I click on play button nothing is displaying in console

Comment: What is displayed in the console during the page loading process that is different between the times that it works and the times it does not work?

Comment: Have you tried putting your code in a `setTimeout()` that delays it 5+ seconds (or better, execute when you click on something) to verify that the issue really is the timing of when your setup code is executed?

Comment: Thank you @Makyen   jQuery(window).on("load", function(){ is working for  me but for ipad this code is not working. I don't know why?

Comment: Have you tried adding a long (several seconds) `setTimeout()` prior to your your code running. Other than controlling the action via a user clickable button, that is usually a good way to determine if it is that the code is having an issue with executing too soon. After making that determination, more investigation can be done to have that delay be the minimum needed, or resolve some other issue, if timing is shown not to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    window.onload = function() {
      //your code comes here
    }

As window.onload is called after all the content and resources of the page are loaded. Hope this helps.